# Use Regex to match string that begins and ends with the same vowel (a, e, i, o, and u) Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Constraints

The length of string  is  .
String  consists of lowercase letters only (i.e., [a-z]).

Output Format

The function must return a RegExp object that matches any string  beginning with and ending in the same vowel.

**Sample Input 0**

bcd

**Sample Output 0**

false

**Sample Input 2**

abcda

**Sample Output 2**

true

*Need Help Plz ???*

Comment: You tend to get best results on this site by showing effort on the homework problem, and also letting us know where you are stuck.  Please consider doing these things here.

Comment: What regex have you used so far? May you show us it with the JS function you've written?

Comment: i don't know how use Regex function to detect begin and end with same character of a string, so that"s why asked qt here

Comment: Search for “regex character class”, “regex back reference”, “regex anchors”.

Comment: [Here's a good playground site](https://regex101.com/) to use when trying to figure these things out.  You'll want to set the flavor to "ECMAScript (JavaScript)".  Also, use the quick reference in the bottom right to help narrow down what you want.  To help you get started, try searching that quick reference for "subpattern"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let re = /^([aeiou]).*\1$/;
let result = "testing".match(re);
```

The key here is `\1` which is a backreference to the first capturing group.

I'll leave it to you to pack this into a function since I don't fully understand the return values you want here.